# Nav pill to be added dynamically in modal using jquery in the middle based on a field value

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-steps

I am using jquery steps and modal.While I need to add a nav-tab dynamically in the middle of 5 tabs based on the value of a field in the first tab.

Following is the image of modal before I have hided the tab[image]

After hiding

[image]

Fixed charges have some fields .Based on one of those field value I need to add payments,dynamically.But it is not showing,when i call $("#pay").show();

```html
  .
  .
 <h1>Summary</h1>
<fieldset>...</fieldset>
<h1 id="pay">Payments</h1>
<fieldset>...</fieldset>
 .
 .
```

I am also using jquery-steps.

Answer (score 0):

We can enable or disable the modal, by using the remove method.

```
$('modaldivid').steps('remove','step number');
```